# Making Calls through Android phone via bluetooth enabled micro controller

Tags: android, command, at-command, phone-call

my end goal is have a microcontroller with bluetooth make calls through any bluetooth enabled phone via bluetooth. I currently have an android phone and it would be great if i could place calls onto that, but i am willing to purchase any phone.

This is for my senior design and i have a lack of knowledge when it comes to the guts of cell phones. I currently can talk from my microcontroller to an Android app called BlueTerm, which is just a terminal for bluetooth, so i know the micro side is ready to go.

Im assuming that to place calls through a phone, you use AT commands?

The android sees my bluetooth device, but says "paired, but not connect". Im assuming there is some standard protocol and allow the cell phone to sync to the bluetooth device?

I dont konw much on this subject. If you could be of any assistance or could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the "bad" news first:

Android itself does not provide any kind of "modem" functionality or the like. Means: There are no AT commands built in to control the phone via bluetooth.

The good news is: The Android phone can be controlled in almost any way you can think of by an appropriate app.

The way you might want to go (if you want to stick to Android) is thus to write your own specific Android app which

1. handles the Bluetooth connection to/from the µC (BlueTerm apparently does this successfully), and
2. accepts commands from the µC received through an established BT connection and then performs any actions on the Android device as desired, like making a call, sending an SMS message, playing a sound, you name it.

For a start on Android app development, you may go to http://developer.android.com/index.html. If you haven't written Android apps before be prepared to learn a *lot* of new concepts.

Maybe you can leverage one or two of the example apps, like ["Bluetooth Chat"](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html).

> The android sees my bluetooth device, but says "paired, but not connect".

This is just the indication that pairing between your µC's Bluetooth module and the phone was successful and that the phone stored the pairing information to allow future connections without repeated input of a PIN. The "not connected" part *should* imply that there is no connection currently established with the named device, however, on my phone I have never seen a "paired and connected" or similar. Not sure why.

> Im assuming there is some standard protocol and allow the cell phone to sync to the bluetooth device?

For Android, Google settled for implementing only RFCOMM Bluetooth connections, a special one of those being the SPP serial port emulation which is probably just what your BT module and BlueTerm use.